# Error building package containing a layout referencing a lookup field's lookup value

Tags: metadata, package

I'm trying to create a package to bundle up my custom apex,layouts and flows and am running into some errors.
I have three custom objects. Object A has a lookup field for Object B. Object B has a lookup field for Object C. Object A has a layout that features a related list containing some fields of Object C. The layout xml features the line 'objectB__c.ObjectC__c' This seems to be the source of the error. It seems like I am unable to capture a layout featuring a lookup field's lookup value. Is this true? The errors are as follows :

'Object A Layout Name : Component [force:relatedListSingleContainer] attribute [relatedListApiName]: Could not find related list [Object B] for entity [Object C]'

The lookup fields are all included in my package. I have no issues when referencing just Object B from Object A.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I have had this problem in deployments and I have been able to solve it in two steps, this seems to be because it is not able to detect all the dependencies at once. I think if you build a version with the lookup fields you can build a second version from the previous one with the layouts and their related lists.